# Invalidate MS Word cache for testing add-ins

Tags: caching, ms-word, ms-office, office-js

I'm working on an add-in for MS Word. We have 2 versions of the manifest file: prod and dev. We manually add them to Word for testing and development. Everything works fine in online versions of Word (regardless of the browser) and on Mac Desktop. The problem is Windows desktop.

On Win10 Desktop (Word 2016) this is what happens: you select a local manifest file for testing. Let's say it's the dev manifest. Everything works fine. You shut down Word, open it up and you select the other manifest, prod. It still displays the dev version of the add in. We inspected web traffic and indeed, it makes requests to dev, instead of prod. It would seem that it is cached. This only happens on Windows, Word 2016 (older versions were not tested and are not supported).

We tried:

- clearing default browser cache (because Word uses the system's default browser)
- clearing Word document cache

It didn't work. Any ideas how to clear the cache to force Word to accept the different manifest version?

PS - this is not an issue in production, this is an issue just for testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try deleting the contents of `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Wef\` (or, safer, just move the contents) before you switch to the other manifest.